# Counting orbits of the standard map

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Consider the [standard map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_map). Might it happen that for some nonzero parameter value $K$ and for some positive integer $q$ that there exist an infinite number of periodic orbits having period $q $  I would also be interested in the same question for "generic" twist maps.   (I was motivated to ask this question by reading the section on zeta functions from Smale's famous ["Differentiable Dynamical Systems"](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1967-73-06/S0002-9904-1967-11798-1/) which was reprinted in [the most recent issue of the Bulletin of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2018-55-03/).)

Comment: Isn’t the map (and its iterates) real analytic? This should prevent accumulation of fixed points of a single power, I think.

Comment: A real analytic map F of a real analytic surface can have a curve's worth of fixed points, or points of any given period $q$. Indeed the standard map for   K = 0 has this property for every period $q$, including $q=1$.   But your question is nice.  I guess that there are three possibilities for the solution set to  $F^q (p) = p$: a finite set (possibly empty) , an analytic curve (possiby singular), or the whole surface.